# Is it possible to understand whether a certificate in Windows cert store imported as "Enable Strong Private Key" protection?

Tags: .net, security, certificate, client-certificates

Is it possible to understand whether a certificate in Windows cert store imported as "Enable Strong Private Key" protection in .NET?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`x509certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) doesn't directly expose this, so unless there is something in its [`Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.extensions.aspx) property there is no direct support in .NET.

(I don't have a certificate with "Enable Strong Private Key" to check directly.)

Comment: I couldn't find any distinguish value in Extensions. You can import any cert again and choose Strong Key if you want to try.